# How do I make the div stay there until the link is clicked again?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a sidebar that only appears when a triangle is clicked and I've gotten to the point where you click the triangle and it appears using:

```
sidebar {
display: none;
}

a:active + .sidebar {
    display: block;
}
```

However as soon as you let go it disappears. How can I make it stay visible until you click the triangle for a second time? Below is the link to full code.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/

Comment: your fiddle is rather different than code in your question

Comment: @imkost That's an extract from the fiddle. You cant ask questions without including code and I didn't want to add all of it.

Comment: @Jacob: That's not an extract from the fiddle. The code here is clearly completely different from what you have there - unless you linked to the wrong fiddle altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use JS to toggle the visibility of the sidebar - a CSS solution is not possible.

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('.sidebar').toggle();
});
```

You will also have to set `display: none` for the `.sidebar` element. I have updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/Vqmaw/3783/

Your modified fiddle has a few issues - you are using MooTools instead of jQuery, and your class selector is improperly formatted.

Comment: @user2214963, this fiddle is same as in your question

Comment: @Terry thanks a heap but can you tell me why when I put it together with my navbar it makes my navbar disappear. Heres the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/3784/

Comment: Check your JsFiddle, and the syntax highlighting. Your `</div>` is not closed properly (line 45) because the `<table>` element is not closed. Pass your HTML through some validator first. And your `</br>` tags are invalid - self-closing tags should be like this - `<br />`

Comment: @Terry you are a legend. You're my new favourite web developer. By the way I love your site I've never seen anything like it. Keep being awesome and thank you again. (This might appear an over reaction but I've only just started web development and that whole thing was mind boggling!) :)